# Отправка данных в БД JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, база-данных, запрос, данные

На странице при нажатии на кнопку необходимо вызывать функцию. Функция должна отправить в БД (таблицу в БД) данные: Имя авторизованного пользователя, курс, который выбрал пользователь (кнопка записи рядом с курсом).

```
function sendDataToRequest()
{
const progUserName = JSON.stringify(progUserName);
const serviceName = JSON.stringify(serviceName);
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open = ('POST', 'serverBD/Request')
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        const user = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
        console.log(user.name, "-", user.age);
    } else {
        console.log("Server response: ", xhr.statusText);
    }
};
xhr.send(progUserName);
xhr.send(serviceName);
```

Есть такой пример, но явно кривой.

Как добить эту функцию? serverBD - БД Request - таблица, в которую необходимо отправить.

Comment: `Как добить эту функцию?` с клиентской частью больше особо не сделать. Запрос придет на сервер и далее все действия должен выполнять серверный скрипт... Вот его нужно делать.

Comment: @lyna а что именно не получается?